# Where is the stackexchange/stackoverflow help, specifically about formatting and markdown?

Tags: support, stackexchange

I read the FAQ page and the About page, but no links to any help topics about the mechanics of using the site.

When I post a comment, can I used formatting?  Where is the format or markdown help?

Okay, when I actually ask a question I get the formatting help sidebar on the right, with a link to the formatting reference https://askubuntu.com/editing-help, but I do not get that link when I'm writing a comment.

Answer (score 3):

The markdown editing help link (question mark) is above the "Your Answer" box. Here is also the [link](https://meta.askubuntu.com/editing-help).